# Weird layout behavior for Android 5.1

Tags: android, android-layout

While testing the app I'm currently developing I noticed some weird behavior of the layout which only occurs for Android 5.1 (tested and working properly for Android 5.0 and less).

When going from portrait to landscape then back to portrait the whole layout seems to move upward and my `ImageView` for the logo gets cut off. (The red part is an `ImageView` of my logo which I can't show.)

[image]

These screenshots are from a 7-inch tablet. This is the only device I have available right now that runs Android 5.1 so I can't confirm if this is a device specific problem.

I need to be able to support different screen sizes and orientation so I have these layouts from the folders `layout-large-land` and `layout-large-port` in my `res` folder.

activity_login.xml from `layout-large-port`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loginImageView"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/banner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

    <com.example.LoginEditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEditText"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/input"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginImageView"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginEditText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_login.xml from `layout-large-land`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loginImageView"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/banner"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.example.LoginEditText
            android:id="@+id/loginEditText"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:hint="@string/input"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/loginEditText"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I used a custom `EditText` since I need to be able to show the keyboard at all times. I don't think this causes the problem since I tried using a plain `EditText` and the problem still occurs. Here it is.

`LoginEditText.java`

```
public class LoginEditText extends EditText {

    public LoginEditText(Context context) {

        super(context);

    }

    public LoginEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {

        super(context, attributeSet);

    }

    public LoginEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defaultStyleAttribute) {

        super(context, attributeSet, defaultStyleAttribute);

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public LoginEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

I also have these options in my manifest inside activity tag for LoginActivity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustPan"
```

From the 3rd screenshot, if I press the home button and then go back to the app the correct portrait layout is shown. It seems that it only occurs if I go from lanscape to portrait.

I tried replacing the `EditText` with other views such as `ImageView` and the problem disappears so my best guess right now is that is where the problem lies.

I apologize for the long question since I really tried resolving this by myself to no avail. Hope someone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have an outer Layout, and then an inner layout which has your content and gravity is set to center. No need for Separate layouts for landscape & portrait.

Comment: Since I need to be able to show the keyboard at all times my layout for landscape shows the `EditText` and `Button` to the right of my logo `ImageView`. For my portrait layout they are positioned below.  So I really need different layouts for each orientation.

Comment: Ok, you should try testing it on an emulator, if issue re-occurs, then the extra space problem & logo getting cut out is from your layout

Comment: The desktop I'm using right now is unable to run an emulator but I'll try this with a more powerful machine when I get home then I'll get back to you.

Comment: Try using `adjustResize` instead of `adjustPan`. In my experience, `adjustPan` causes all kinds of problems, and if your layout is not flexible enough to work with `adjustResize`, then you probably have a problem with your layout (in my opinion).